# repetitive sequence of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to spot if user entered some repetitive sequence of characters in an input field, for example:

1. if the user types `"qwabcerabctyabcuiabcop"` 
   wanna catch `"abc"`
2. if `"aaaqw111er111ty"`
   wanna catch `"111"`
3. but if `"aaa"`
   wanna catch nothing, null

Comment: Will the repetitive sequence always be 3 characters long?

Comment: what about `aaba`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some effort instead of asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: do you want to pass specific sequence to track or just any random sequence should be automatically detected in latin a-z0-9 and special chars?

Comment: I think this is the classic longest common subsequence problem. here's the solution in C++. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/repeated-subsequence-length-2/

Comment: [You may use this regex `(.+)(?:(?!\1).)+?\1.*`](https://regex101.com/r/TBGYIN/1)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
"qwabcerabctyabcuiabcop".match(/(.{3})(?=.*\1)/)
```

The regex will match any 3 consecutives chars which will be repeted.

`(.{3})` match 3 consecutives characters
`(?=` positive lookahead
`.*` any sequence of characters
`\1)` the previous 3 consecutives character match

Comment: OP has been asked whether the sequence will always be 3 characters long.  Until that's answered this could well be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I changed "{3}" to "{3,}" to match substrings longer then 3 chars